# Shell script to remove files from multiple host

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sh, xargs

I have a script, which ssh’s into a list of host’s and deletes files. The problem that I am facing is that when the deletion happens the console asks’s for password.

To get around that I know use the below code which hardcodes the password

```
time cat ../hosts.txt | xargs -P 16 -I foo ssh foo ' echo "MYPASSWORD" | sudo -kS rm -rf /tmp/randomfile*'
```

Is there any way to avoid hardcoding the password?

Comment: you can setup a ssh key

Comment: One more option is combination of `Ansible` and `sshpass`

Comment: This is a system configuration issue. You should configure the remote hosts to allow you to log in as a user who doesn't need to use `sudo` to remove the files. This can be as simple as logging in as `root`, or something safer like creating a special user who can remove those files, but not really do anything else.

Comment: (Or rather, configure `sudo` so that the special user doesn't need to enter a password to execute this specific command.)

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a [ssh-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent).

I would suggest using a ssh-key, you could check this article describing how to create it and add it to your ssh-agent:

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Comment: `ssh-agent` won't help with `sudo` requesting a password.